# Adding Storage space to RAID1 setup

Tags: 18.04, server, raid, mdadm

Currently I have an Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS server with 2 6TB HDs setup in RAID1 like so:

```
~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdd2[0] sdb2[1]
      5859412992 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 1/44 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk
```

The space on the drives will run out soon so I bought 2 16TB HDs I want to add (already physically connected in the server but not setup). From what I understand I cannot add these as a separate raid1 configuration (16TB mirroring + 6TB mirroring) and need to move to raid 10. Is this true? I can't just have the two 16TB also in RAID1 and mounted as a different folder?

Can I use the 2x 16TB HDs in combination with the 2x 6TB ones in a RAID 10 or do they all have to be the same size?

How do I go about adding the 2 HDs and migrating to the new RAID setup without losing the existing data?

**Business requirements:**

1. Redundancy / Fault tolerance
2. Fast read/write (big data)
3. Increase HD space, does not necessarily have to act as one drive (can be a new mount point / folder if easier)

**UPDATE:**

Following the instructions at the link below, I added the two drives as an additional raid1 using the following commands, rebooted the computer, and now can't ssh into it.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-18-04#creating-a-raid-1-array

```
~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME            SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda            14.6T                   disk
sdb             5.5T                   disk
├─sdb1          953M vfat              part
└─sdb2          5.5T linux_raid_member part
  └─md0         5.5T LVM2_member       raid1
    ├─vg-swap 186.3G swap              lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─vg-root  93.1G ext4              lvm   /
    ├─vg-tmp   46.6G ext4              lvm   /tmp
    ├─vg-var   23.3G ext4              lvm   /var
    └─vg-home   5.1T ext4              lvm   /home
sdc            14.6T                   disk
sdd             5.5T                   disk
├─sdd1          953M vfat              part  /boot/efi
└─sdd2          5.5T linux_raid_member part
  └─md0         5.5T LVM2_member       raid1
    ├─vg-swap 186.3G swap              lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─vg-root  93.1G ext4              lvm   /
    ├─vg-tmp   46.6G ext4              lvm   /tmp
    ├─vg-var   23.3G ext4              lvm   /var
    └─vg-home   5.1T ext4              lvm   /home
```

```
~$ sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdc
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md1
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/md1
sudo mount /dev/md1 /mnt/md1
```

```
~$ df -h -x devtmpfs -x tmpfs
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root   92G  7.5G   79G   9% /
/dev/sdd1            952M  4.4M  947M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/vg-var    23G  6.0G   16G  28% /var
/dev/mapper/vg-tmp    46G   54M   44G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg-home  5.1T  2.5T  2.4T  51% /home
/dev/md1              15T   19M   14T   1% /mnt/md1
```

```
~$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=mypc:0 UUID=someweirdhash
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=mypc:1 UUID=someweirdhash
```

```
~$ sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-166-generic
```

```
~$ sudo reboot
```

***Cannot ssh into server after reboot.***

DID NOT DO THIS: (what are the last two zeros below?) I wasn't sure what this command does and imagined it could set the new array to be the boot one, so maybe not running it broke it:

```
~$ echo '/dev/md1 /mnt/md1 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Comment: If point two is a legitimate requirement, then RAID1 is not the solution. As for the manner of going about it, I do not see why your system could not support multiple RAID arrays on different mount points. One of six gigabytes and the second of sixteen 

Comment: RAID0 can be all different sizes, but a RAID1 is a mirror so they have to be the same.  However, a RAID0+1 is a mirror of stripes where you could mirror a striped set of RAID0 drives but both would have to be the same size like a RAID0 of a 6TB+16TB.  But growing a RAID, etc always has an inherit risk of loss of data so always best to make sure you have a full backup before performing any RAID changes.  See: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/raid10-vs-raid01/ for a good explanation of RAID10 vs RAID0+1

Comment: @matigo I tried adding the two new drives as an additional raid1 and now can't ssh into the server (see update in the question). I tried connecting a monitor to it but that didn't work for some reason even before these changes so not sure what to do now.